# RVMSUDO not using environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I generated a set of env vars that I have set in my .bash_profile

that didn't work when using RVMSUDO

then i tried rvm export, and on viewing rvmsudo env, they gain rvm_old_$nameofvariable instead of $nameofvariable

i have also tried adding 
export name=value 
to the .rvmc in the project and that dosen't seem to get reflected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As per:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/bin/rvmsudo#L83

You should prefix your environment variable with "http_" or "PATH" to let rvm pass this variable along.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to copy and modify rvmsudo so that it preserved ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the root account in order to install ruby-oci8:

```
]$ diff `which rvmsudo` rvmsudo 
84c84
<       GREP_OPTIONS="" \grep -E '^rvm|^gemset|^http_|^PATH|^IRBRC|RUBY|GEM' |
---
>       GREP_OPTIONS="" \grep -E '^rvm|^gemset|^http_|^PATH|^IRBRC|^ORA|^LD_LIBRARY|RUBY|GEM' |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing ,

```
rvmsudo <environment variables> <command>
```

instead of

```
<environment variables>  rvmsudo <command>
```